# Pivot Table color issue

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have an issue with Pivot table color formatting. My sheet is completely grey color. When I insert pivot table using vba, the color of 2-3 columns outside pivot table changes to white. I am not sure how to fix this. Also when I toogle on filters on pivot table, some data on rows reduce and color changes. When data reduces, it should preserve the sheet color. Now there comes a white spaces. Any ways to  fix this? Thank you.

Comment: A sample screenshot and the code you're using would be helpful here. For more detail, see [reprex].

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have made your sheet grey by manually changing the background color  of all cells, is this correct?

Try modifying the cell-style "Normal" to grey background and changing all cells back to Normal style (you can do this by finding the Normal style in the ribbon's Home tab > cell-styles, and right click on Normal).

The problem originates from Pivot Tables changing the format of cells they use, and whenever they release cells they no longer need they revert them back to Normal instead of keeping track of their previous format.

Comment: Yes, I have made the sheet grey manually.Any ways to fix the pivot table format cells. When they reduce the cells or row, the background color doesn't change to normal.